# angle between two surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Thank you all.
How can I find the angle between two surfaces:
,  at point (1,2,1)?
If I calculate the angle between the two normals at this point, is it true method? thank you all answers.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, the angle between the planes will be equal to the angle between the normals.